# Getting different year when converting a timestamp column to char using TO_CHAR

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

This is from Oracle 12C and I even tried from online Oracle compiler

Can someone explain why it is happening like this
Here are the simple steps that I am following

-- Created a GTT. Getting issue with Physical table as well

create global temporary table GTT_A
( b timestamp(3));

-- Inserted a date with Year 1901

Insert into GTT_A values ('01-JAN-1901');

-- When retrieving, direct column is giving year as 19 and when converted to char, it is giving 2019. Is there some kind of explanation for this

Select b, to_char(b,'mm-dd-yyyy') from GTT_A;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'01-JAN-1901'` is not a timestamp, it is a string.

Don't insert a string; use a date literal (it will be cast to timestamp):

```sql
Insert into GTT_A values (DATE '1901-01-01');
```

or a timestamp literal if you want to include the time component:

```sql
Insert into GTT_A values (TIMESTAMP '1901-01-01 00:00:00');
```

Or, if you want to use a string then use `TO_DATE` with a format model to explicitly convert from the string to a date:

```sql
Insert into GTT_A values (
  TO_DATE(
    '01-JAN-1901',
    'DD-MON-YYYY',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'
  )
);
```

or `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```sql
Insert into GTT_A values (
  TO_TIMESTAMP(
    '01-JAN-1901',
    'DD-MON-YYYY',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'
  )
);
```

If you rely on implicit conversion then Oracle will try to implicitly convert your string to a date and your query:

```sql
Insert into GTT_A values ('01-JAN-1901');
```

Is effectively converted to:

```sql
Insert into GTT_A values (
  TO_TIMESTAMP(
    '01-JAN-1901',
    ( SELECT value
      FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
      WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT' )
  )
);
```

Each user can set their own session parameters at **ANY** time so your query can work one minute and then the user updates their session parameters and your query stops working without having changed your query. Don't rely on implicit conversions; make it so you don't need to convert anything by using a date/timestamp literal or use an explicit conversion.

Comment: Thank you for your response. By converting into date, i am getting correct results

Answer (score 1):

check your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` using

```
SELECT
  value
FROM
  V$NLS_PARAMETERS
WHERE
  parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT';
```

and alter the year to four digits using the below command before insert for example

```
     alter session set nls_timestamp_format='DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SSXFF AM'
```

Comment: Thank you. By changing the format, even if I insert string into date, i am getting correct results.

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni - changing the session `nls_???_format` is only a temporary measure, which perhaps is OK in development; but for production, that is not the correct approach. Never pass strings in and expect an **implicit** conversion. Use date and timestamp literals (see documentation for those), or use TO_TIMESTAMP() and similar, **with explicit nls_timestamp_format (or similar)** in the function call.